# Jquery - Use alt tag as caption within lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, lightbox, elementor

So I currently have an image carousel which when you click a lightbox appears, but you cannot add a caption within the lightbox.

What I am trying to achieve is adding an alt tag to the gallery, I then want to run through each item and take this attribute and add it within each item in the lightbox. The img src urls match so that is something else to think about i guess. I currently have the below.

```
jQuery('.elementor-image-gallery .gallery-item a').each(function() {
  jQuery('img', this).each(function() {

    var caption = jQuery(this).attr('alt');
    var url = jQuery(this).attr('src');

    setTimeout(function(){
     var lightbox_img = jQuery('img.elementor-lightbox-image');
        lightbox_img.after('<span class="caption">' + caption + '</span>');

    }, 3000);

  });
});
```

I can simply grab the alt tag fine but where the lightbox is outside of the scope of I believe this is where it's not working.

If I `console.log lightbox_img` i get undefined.

Markup hierachy is something like

```
body
-- gallery
---- gallery item
-- lightbox
---- lightbox item
```

Comment: console.log(caption) in the setTimeout function if the console.log output is undefined then declare the caption in the setTimeout

Comment: Worked out the issue, the markup for the lightbox doesn't initiate until you click an item